# unix file fetch by timestamp

Tags: unix, file-sorting

I have a list of files that get added to my work stream. They are csv with a date time stamp to indicate when they are created. I need to pick up each file in the order of the datetime in the file name to process it. Here is a sample list that I get:

```
Workprocess_2016_11_11T02_00_12.csv
Workprocess_2016_11_11T06_50_45.csv
Workprocess_2016_11_11T10_06_18.csv
Workprocess_2016_11_11T14_23_00.csv
```

How would I compare the files to search for the oldest one and work towards the chronological newer file? The day the files are dumped is the same, so I can only use from the  timestamp in file name.

Comment: Is the "Workprocess" prefix the same for all files?

Comment: Thanks for considering my question. Yes, that is common. I would like to pick up the correct file (in order) and rename it to xyz and then that xyz would be the file to be used in the rest of the process.

Answer (score 0):

The beneficial aspect of that date time format is that it sorts the same lexically and chronologically. So all you need is

```
for file in *.csv; do
 mv "$f" xyz
 process xyz
done
```

Comment: Glenn, I need to compare those files to see which is the oldest and use that first, then work towards the newer one. if the file name has date and time in the file name, what is the way to extract those and use in a nested compare?

Comment: You don't need to. Do this: `echo *.csv` -- is the order of the output correct?

Comment: Yes, I was always able to get that. Maybe I was over complicating my problem :) Thanks for your help